# ReactJS, Red Screen Unable to download JS Bundle

Tags: android, reactjs, reactjs-native

My generated reactjs native project compiles and starts correclty - almost, because I'm getting a red screen with the following message

What is wrong with my configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is described here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html

You have to start packager manually, exactly how it is there explained:

```
node node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html